# sharepoint 2010 get value of choice field through api call

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint list `ImageList`, i have a column which stores its type

The column name is `ImageType`

the choices are *"profile pic","thumbnail"* etc

i want to fetch these choice values for this field

i tried accessing it using

```
http://myintranet:2010/sites/ImagesGallery/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ImageList?$expand=ImageType
```

but it is not containing the choice values in it!

How can i get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query:

```
http://myintranet:2010/sites/ImagesGallery/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ImageList?$expand=ImageType
```

returns list items values for List resource only.

In order to retrieve field resource itself, the different endpoint have to be specified, in particular:

```
http://myintranet:2010/sites/ImagesGallery/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ImageListImageType
```

> It is assumed that list name is `ImageList` and field name is
>   `ImageType`

**Example**

```
$.getJSON(endpointUrl)
.done(function(data)
{
    //print field choice options
    data.d.results.forEach(function(item){ 
       console.log(item.Value);
    });

})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: So you just comebine the list name and the field name?